A tribe film about a male who is captured and stripped naked by women
It is an old colour film similar to The Naked Prey (1965-1966). The spoken language is English and the period of film-making should be between 1960-1970.
The location of the movie is in some kind of rain forest.
There is a scene where a male actor is tied up and stripped of his clothes by some tribe members. In one moment, a man takes his watch and smashes it to pieces (they have never seen one before. Then a tribe woman rips of his undies and plays with his genitals.
I think the actor is Charlton Heston or someone who looks very similar.

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.
